facing problem with sending multiple files
so im coding with vue and im using cloudconvert api which converts my files to pdf and gets me the number of pages, also im using a package called dropzone which i can drop files into it and it handles them and sends them it also does other restrictions that helps alot
the thing is when i click "upload document" the dropzone sends the files before i create a job at cloud convert by sending post request because when i create a job it will give me the params that i need to send with the file and the upload link which both will be used by dropzone to send its request
now dropzone has a parameter called "sending" which you can pass to it a function called "onsending" that has the FormData of the file before sending it, inside the onsending i call a function that creates the job
i can make it work by sending 1 file and i can do that by putting the handleimage() function in uploaddocument function but when i want to send multiple files i thought that if i put handleimage() inside onsending it would work but it didnt what happened is it sends the files before handleimage() gets the Parameters FormData
purpose and role of each function
handleimage: creates the job in cloudconvert
uploaddocument: initiate the upload process
onsending: runs each time before sending the files or before sending the request
This is the code :
<template>
        <p>job ID: {{ jobID }}</p>

<br>
<p>Parameters: {{ pramnamed }}</p>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="dropzone-icon">
      <img src="@/assets/dropzone_icon.svg" alt="Dropzone Icon" />
    </div>

    <DropZone
      :dropzoneClassName="customDropzoneClass"
      :dropzoneMessageClassName="customDropzoneMessageClass"
      :dropzoneItemClassName="customDropzoneItemClass"
      :dropzoneDetailsClassName="customDropzoneDetailsClass"
      :maxFiles="Number(10)"
      
      ref="dropzoneRef"
      :uploadOnDrop="false"
          :url= this.urld
      :headers="{'Authorization' : 'Bearer '}"
      @sending="onSending"
      
      :acceptedFiles="[
        'pdf',
        'eps',
        'jpg',
        'tiff',
        'png',
        'JPEG',
        'svg',
        'pages',
        'doc',
        'docx',
        'ppt',
        'pptx',
        'xls',
        'xlsx',
        'txt',
      ]"
    />
   
  </div>
 
<button @click="UploadDocument">upload document</button>

  <p class="middle-align">Paste <a href="" @click.prevent="openImageURLInput">URL</a> image link</p>
  <div v-if="showModal" class="modal" @click="closeModal">
    <div class="modal-content" @click.stop>
      <span class="close-button" @click="closeModal">&times;</span>
      <input type="text" v-model="imageUrl" placeholder="Enter image URL" />
      <button @click="handleImageUrl">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

 
<div class= boxingg>
  <h2 class="faq-title">Leave the printing<br>
to us!</h2>
<p class="paragraphh" >Simply upload your documents and insert coins and your documents will be printed immediately </p>
<div class="containerr">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="@/assets/recycle pic.svg" class="imagee" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="faq-title">What is Bunt?<br>
to us!</h2>
<p class="paragraphh" >Is commercial vending machine that prints paper on demand, we have built it to<br> be as easy as taking a picture by having vending machine accept as many types of files as possible.</p>
  <div class="faq-container">
    <h2 class="faq-title">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
  <div v-for="(faq, index) in faqs" :key="index" class="faq-item">
    <div class="faq-question" @click="toggleFaqAnswer(index)">
      <span>{{ faq.question }}</span>
      <span class="faq-arrow" :class="{ 'flipped': activeFaqIndex === index }">
        <img src="@/assets/cheveron-down.svg" alt="Chevron Down" />
      </span>
    </div>
    <div v-if="activeFaqIndex === index" class="faq-answer">
      <p>{{ faq.answer }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import { DropZone } from "dropzone-vue";
//local data storage
import { useFilesStore } from '@/stores/files';
//api logic
// import {taskss} from "@/API/cloudconvert";
//css code
import '@/assets/styles/homepage.css';

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
     
      jobID: "",
      urld: "https://eu-central.storage.cloudconvert.com/tasks",
      pramnamed: { },
                         
    }
  },

  components: {
    DropZone,
  },
  name: "HomePageContent",










 
  methods: {
     onSending(file, xhr, formData) {
    // Ensure handleImage runs before modifying formData
   this.handleImage();

    console.log("pramnamed in onSending:", this.pramnamed); // Debugging line

    // Ensure pramnamed is properly defined
    if (this.pramnamed) {
      Object.entries(this.pramnamed).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        formData.append(key, value);
      });
    } else {
      console.error('pramnamed is undefined or null');
    }
}},









  setup() {
    const dropzoneRef = ref(null);
    const customDropzoneClass = "my-custom-dropzone";
    const customDropzoneMessageClass = "my-custom-dropzone-message";
    const customDropzoneItemClass = "my-custom-dropzone-item";
    const customDropzoneDetailsClass = "my-custom-dropzone-details";
    const showModal = ref(false);
    const imageUrl = ref("");
    const activeFaqIndex = ref(-1);
    const filesStore = useFilesStore();
    const faqs = [
      {
        question: "What is the price to print 1 paper?",
        answer: "The price to print 1 paper is $0.10.",
      },
      {
        question: "What file types does the machine accept?",
        answer: "The machine accepts    pdf, eps, jpg, tiff, png, JPEG, svg, pages, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx, txt file types.",
      },
      {
        question: "How long does it take before order code expires?",
        answer: "The order code expires in 3 days.",
      },
      {
        question: "How many files can I upload?",
        answer: "You can upload up to 10 files at a time.",
      },
    ];

    function openImageURLInput() {
      showModal.value = true;
    }
    function closeModal() {
      showModal.value = false;
      imageUrl.value = "";
    }
    function toggleFaqAnswer(index) {
      if (activeFaqIndex.value === index) {
        activeFaqIndex.value = -1;
      } else {
        activeFaqIndex.value = index;
      }
    }


   



async function UploadDocument(){
  
       await dropzoneRef.value.processQueue();
      const tasks = await waitForJobCompletion(this.jobID);
      console.log("Completed Tasks:", tasks);
      const metadataTask = tasks.find((task) => task.name === "task-2");
      if (!metadataTask) {
        throw new Error("Metadata task not found");
      }
      filesStore.addFile({
        id: this.jobID,
        name: fileMetadata.FileName,
        pageCount: fileMetadata.PageCount,
        size: fileMetadata.FileSize,
      });
    }





    const message = ref("");
    async function waitForJobCompletion(jobId) {
      while (true) {
        const jobResponse = await axios.get(
          `https://api.cloudconvert.com/v2/jobs/${jobId}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization:
                "Bearer ",
            },
          }
        );

        console.log("Job Response:", jobResponse.data);

        const jobStatus = jobResponse.data.data.status;
        const tasks = jobResponse.data.data.tasks;



        if (jobStatus === "finished") {
          return tasks;
        } else if (jobStatus === "error") {
          throw new Error("Job failed");
        }

        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // Wait for 5 seconds before polling again
      }
    }



    async function handleImage() {
      
      try {
        // Step 1: Create a job
        const jobResponse = await axios.post(
          "https://api.cloudconvert.com/v2/jobs",
          {
            tasks: {
              "import-1": {
                operation: "import/upload",
              },
              "task-1": {
                operation: "convert",
                input: ["import-1"],
                output_format: "pdf",
              }, 
              "task-2": {
                operation: "metadata",
                input: ["task-1"],
              },
              "export-1": {
                operation: "export/url",
                input: ["task-1"],
                inline: false,
                archive_multiple_files: false,
              },
            },
            tag: "jobbuilder",
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization:
                "Bearer ",
            },
          }
        );
        // Access reactive data properties using this
        this.jobID = jobResponse.data.data.id;
       const importTask = jobResponse.data.data.tasks.find((task) => task.name === "import-1");
    if (importTask) {
      this.urld = importTask.result.form.url;
      this.pramnamed = importTask.result.form.parameters;
 
    } else {
      throw new Error("Import task not found");
    }


     
    this.message = `Uploaded document successfully with ID: ${jobId}`;
  } catch (error) {
        this.message = `Error uploading document: ${error.response ? error.response.data.message : error.message
          }`;
      }
}





    return {
      customDropzoneClass,
      customDropzoneMessageClass,
      customDropzoneItemClass,
      customDropzoneDetailsClass,
     
      openImageURLInput,
      showModal,
      imageUrl,
      closeModal,
    
      
      faqs,
      activeFaqIndex,
      toggleFaqAnswer,

      dropzoneRef,

//API
waitForJobCompletion,
handleImage,
UploadDocument,
message,



    };
  },
});
</script>

enter image description here
i want to be able to send multiple files but so far i was able to send 1 file only
